# insert data in new row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

we get data with XMLHttpRequest from costume( mocki.io and fake json) url, I want to insert name and city in new  tag! but in this code set all data element.name and element.city in one table row!!
we should have 4  and in every tr tag we should have two td tags include name and city data.

can help me to set pair (name, city) in new table row?

thanks.

```html
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>AJAX</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 style="text-align:center" id="data"></h1>
            <table id="table" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>city</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="name"></td>
                        <td id="city"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <script>
    
            // Create XML HTTP Request
            let xHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xHTTP.open('GET','https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8');
            xHTTP.onload = () => {
                if (xHTTP.status == 200 && xHTTP.readyState == 4){
                }
            }
            
            // Separeted Object Data
            function processResult(result){
                result.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element);
                    console.log(element.name);
                    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML  +=  element.name + '</br>';
                    document.getElementById('city').innerHTML  +=  element.city + '</br>';
                });
            }
    
            // GET DATA from URL
            let response;
            xHTTP.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xHTTP.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
                    console.log('AJAX was succeed');
                    response = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    console.log('my response is: ',response);
                    console.log(typeof(response));
                    processResult(response); 
                }
            };
    
            // SEND Result to server
            xHTTP.send();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest it was quite difficult to understand your question as the way you explained it.

What i could understand is, that you are trying to display your fetched data correctly in your created table.

**Your Problem:**

You are facing a problem because you are changing the innerHTML of your `<td> (table data)` in plain text without wrapping it within a new `<tr> (table row)`.

To be more precise: You would need a new table row for every result (movie and name) to display the table correctly. Right now you are placing all of your result in just one `<tr>`with two `<td>` inside. To match your results you would need `4 <tr> with 2 <td>` inside.

**Possible solution 1:** *Fast and supported by all Browser Versions*

The much easier way of ensuring that your table is displayed correctly (also for older Browser Versions), is to access your `<tbody>` directly and appending the new `<tr>, <td> and your data` within the `.innerHTML` of your `<tbody>` like this:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AJAX</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center" id="data"></h1>
    <table id="table" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      // Create XML HTTP Request
      let xHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xHTTP.open(
        "GET",
        "https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8"
      );
      xHTTP.onload = () => {
        if (xHTTP.status == 200 && xHTTP.readyState == 4) {
        }
      };

      // Separeted Object Data
      function processResult(result) {
        result.forEach((element, i) => {
          document.getElementById(
            "tableData"
          ).innerHTML += `<tr id="result${i}"><td id=MovieName${i}>${element.name}</td><td id=CityName${i}>${element.city}</td></tr>`;
        });
      }

      // GET DATA from URL
      let response;
      xHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xHTTP.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
          response = JSON.parse(this.response);
          processResult(response);
        }
      };

      // SEND Result to server
      xHTTP.send();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**Possible solution 2:**
*This solution works, but is much slower.*

You could try to create a new table row with [`.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement?retiredLocale=de) for every result that you get from your request, append two new TextNodes (with [`.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode?retiredLocale=de)) and then append your data (with [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild?retiredLocale=de)) "movie" and "city" to `two different <td>` within the new created table row. Afterwards its quite easy to `append the whole <tr>` to your actual table to display the data correctly.

If you would do it this way it could look something like this:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AJAX</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center" id="data"></h1>
    <table id="table" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      // Create XML HTTP Request
      let xHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xHTTP.open(
        "GET",
        "https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8"
      );
      xHTTP.onload = () => {
        if (xHTTP.status == 200 && xHTTP.readyState == 4) {
        }
      };

      // Separeted Object Data
      function processResult(result) {
        result.forEach((element) => {
          const tableRowNode = document.createElement("tr");
          const tableNodeMovie = document.createElement("td");
          const tableNodeCity = document.createElement("td");
          const movieTextNode = document.createTextNode(element.name);
          const cityTextNode = document.createTextNode(element.city);
          tableNodeMovie.appendChild(movieTextNode);
          tableNodeCity.appendChild(cityTextNode);
          tableRowNode.appendChild(tableNodeMovie);
          tableRowNode.appendChild(tableNodeCity);
          document.getElementById("tableData").appendChild(tableRowNode);
        });
      }

      // GET DATA from URL
      let response;
      xHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xHTTP.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
          response = JSON.parse(this.response);
          processResult(response);
        }
      };

      // SEND Result to server
      xHTTP.send();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the first solution, you could also use the insertAdjacentHTML() function, which would allow to sort the elements in ascending or descending order.
Great examples!